# Angular 4/ES5 routing without components

Tags: angular, routes

Is there anyway to route links so that I don't have to create a component for each URL?

I was able to do this in Angular 1.

Comment: Can you add some example of where do you want to route? In angularjs, you could also route to controllers - now there are only components, but it is basically the same. You could also have one component for multiple URLs (and handle the state of it dynamically based on current URL).

Comment: I have a PHP application that has standard routing Module/Controller/Method. I want to be able to just add a link User/Index/Login add the <router-outlet></router-outlet> and have the content be loaded in. Instead I have to add a path, create a component and set the template from there.

Comment: So the content of component will be loaded dynamically from PHP?

Comment: And it will be just plain HTML content, no angular directives/components? Maybe it would be best if you could add example of what you want in angularjs (v1). Also its not clear whether the PHP application is behind the angular app, or how is it connected or not...

Comment: Yes the content would be loaded from the PHP side. Here's my Angular 1 code: https://github.com/anoblet/application/blob/master/View/Layout/Index.phtml

Comment: The technique I used for v1 allowed for ng-directives.

Comment: Just ended up using the cli which made things easier.